# vector double calculations to find angle in C++

Tags: c++, double

I am having below code

```
constexpr double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
cout << "RAV dot product is " << normalization1.first.DotProduct(normalization2.first) << endl;
cout << "acos of 1 is " << std::acos(1) * (180/pi) << endl;
double dotproductvalue = normalization1.first.DotProduct(normalization2.first);
cout << "dot product value: " << std::fixed << dotproductvalue << endl;
cout << "RAV angel is " << std::acos(dotproductvalue) * (180 / pi) << endl;
return std::acos(normalization1.first.DotProduct(normalization2.first)) * (180 / pi); // return in
```

degrees

When I run above product I am observing below output

Question 3:

```
Intersection of lines 1.182000x_1+ 5.562000x_2 = 6.744000
  and 1.773000x_1+ 8.343000x_2 = 9.525000
 are
RAV dot product is 1.000000
acos of 1 is 0.000000
dot product value: 1.000000
RAV angel is -nan(ind)
```

I am not able find what is bug in above code Why angel is shown as -nan(ind) instead of zero?

Please help in debugging.

Thanks

Comment: How can we tell without seeing normalization and DotProduct?

Comment: I see that you are using `180/pi`. You do know that the math functions are in radians,

Comment: I tested the last half of your code snippet in godbolt to see if NAN would be returned, but 0.000 is the result: https://godbolt.org/z/d6c4fr
What compiler are you using?

Comment: It may be because `dotproductvalue` is slightly larger than 1. Try increasing number of digits to print after the dot. For example printing 30 digits should be good.